# List<Structure> in java

Tags: java, arrays

How I can instantiate a object  in the List e.g

i like to search for begin in the file , if it finds then add the store the code after it. here is the example

```
public abstract class Structure 
{   
    private List<Structure> structureList = new ArrayList<Structure>();

    protected void setStructure(Filemanager file, String line)
    {
    /*
     * set all values at the object structure
     */
    line = file.getSourceLine();

    while (!line.contains("END_"))
    {
                    if (line.contains("TRANSLATE"))
                    {

                    }
                    else if (line.contains("BEGIN_OBJECT"))
                    {
                        structureList.add(new FunctionalStructure(line));
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        setValue(line);
                    }
                    line = file.getSourceLine();
            }
    }

    protected abstract void setValue(String line);  
}

public abstract class FunctionalStructure extends Structure 
{ 
    private String name;
    public FunctionalStructure(String line) 
    { 
        super();
        this.name = line.substring(line.indexOf("\"")+1, line.lastIndexOf("\"")); 
    } 
    public String getName() 
    { 
        return this.name; 
    } 
    public List<Structure> Startfunctional() 
    { 
        return null;
    } 
    protected abstract void setValue(String line); 
}
```

I have problem in in instantiate structureList.add(new FunctionalStructure(line));

Can anyone please tell what is wrong in the above line

Comment: which exactly problem? doesn't compile? throws at runtime? silently doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: at  structureList.add(new FunctionalStructure(line));
error  that the  Cannot instantiate the type

Comment: What does the FunctionalStructure class look like

Comment: is new FunctionalStructure(line) extends a Structure ?

Comment: Does `FunctionalStructure extends Structure` ? And ensure `FunctionalStructure`is not abstract

Comment: @Ganderous can you please post your class definition of FunctionalStructure

Comment: thanks @ KDitragilla, incidently I make FunctionalStructure(line){
 as an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `FunctionalStructure` must be an abstract class (which presumably extends `Structure`). You cannot instantiate an abstract class.

This is why you get the error like:

```
Cannot instantiate the type FunctionalStructure
```

If you created the FunctionalStructure class, perhaps you accidentally marked it as abstract. Assuming it implements the setValue(String) method, you could remove the abstract modifier from the class declaration.

Alternatively, use a suitable concrete class extending `FunctionalStructure` in the API you are using.

Alternatively, use an anonymous inner class:

```
structureList.add(new FunctionalStructure(line){
    public void setValue(String value) {
        // your implementation here
    }
});
```

Comment: If it's an interface, how does it happen to have a constructor?

Comment: Interface extending classes, WOW! brand new !

Comment: Who said it was a class and had a a constructor? The error message is what you get in Eclipse when you try to instantiate an interface.

Comment: @sudocode: `Structure` is a class, so if `FunctionalStructure` is an interface, it cannot extend `Structure`.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I make FunctionalStructure(line){
an abstract class, which was wrong..

Answer (score 0):

you might find example below helpful to understand the concept :-

```
package pack;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyGeneric<A> obj = new MyGeneric<A>() ;


        //obj.add(new C()) ; //don't compile
        obj.testMethod(new A()) ; //fine
        obj.testMethod(new B()) ; //fine
    }
}

class A{}

class C{}

class B extends A{}

class MyGeneric<T>{

    public void testMethod(T t) {

    }
}
```

EDIT : So, there must be a IS-A relation between **Structure and FunctionalStructure** to successfully compile the code.